# Why are the textures rendering with white lines and dots?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I've used some stock collada files and imported them into Blender. I did not make any changes to the models, aside from reducing their size. For testing purposes, the runway can be found [here](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/930292c86a6ed239e7c3f46142396856/Runway-Model).

In the below picture, you'll see that the models look fine until the scene is rendered. My output setting is 1920 x 1080 with 100% resolution and 15% compression.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Pre-render vs Render]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/945/artifacts-in-rendered-geometry-which-appears-okay-in-opengl-solid-view/946#946 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73556/weird-texture-issues-when-importing-collada-from-sketchup/73558#73558

Comment: Basically looks like Z-Fighting. Either you have duplicate geometry in your objects, or your surfaces are too close together, leading to precision issues.